# Dividing/Multiplying Numbers Stored in two memory locations

Tags: algorithms, arithmetic, memory-access, multiplication

I have two numbers x and y.
The upper bits of x are stored at location m, while
the lower bits of x are stored at location n.
The upper bits of y are stored at location i, while
the lower bits of y are stored at location j.

I have the division operator "/" and the multiplication operator "*", but only for numbers stored at a single memory location.  For example, if q was small enough to be stored at memory location a, and p was small enough to be stored at memory location b, then I can compute q/p and store this in a single memory location.

The question is: how do I compute x/y and x*y in the fastest way?  I was thinking along the lines of using / and * in places where I am only multiplying parts of the number at one memory location, because this would be faster than strictly using repeated addition or repeated subtraction.

For specifics, I am using the language 7800basic, where numbers can only be 1 byte large.  And I am looking to be able to multiple and divide larger numbers in the fastest way.

Comment: For multiplication take a look on [Karatsuba multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm). For dividing I think you  can adopt [Long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division) method from school.

Comment: For a multiplication of numbers twice the word length, forget any asymptotically advantageous methods, including Toom-Cook (which includes Karatsuba).

Comment: Why's that, Greybeard?  Surely Karatsuba is better than repeated addition. ...

Comment: What methods for division and multiplication of such numbers have you used up to now? How many of each can you get completed in, say, 5 seconds, and how many would be enough? Is this an exercise, of are you pushing a "real" 6502? Can you incorporate code not generated by `7800basic`? Is my impression correct that the biggest product supported is 255 (15*17)?

Comment: I have only implemented repeated addition and repeated subtraction successfully.  My testing method is not user friendly in the sense that I have to restart my Atari emulator every time I want to run my code. And the output is just sprites (images) on the screen which are numbers.  So I haven't done such a test yet. I've just noticed that my create_line implementation (which uses these 2 byte numbers) is a little sluggish, which will cause problems when I do operations on top of this.  255 is the largest such number. I don't understand what pushing a 6502 is or incorporating non 7800basic code

Comment: When you implement multi-"word" multiplication on a machine (virtual or hardware) without even */-instructions operating on single words, the shift algorithms are your best bet. While it is possible to do so in BASIC (what with 7800basic supporting `CARRY`), assembler/"machine code" would more easily lend itself to the task. You specify that you want two two byte factors. Do you need/can you actually use a four byte product? If you want a two byte product, can you use a two-by-one-byte multiplication/can you assure that one specific factor will not exceed 255?

Comment: So I most likely will not need 4 bytes in my product (I'll need 3 at the most). On the other hand, my factors probably need to be 2 bytes each to either represent a large enough number or represent a precise enough number. Why do you mention possibly using factors that are 2 bytes and 1 byte?  I know this can make the algorithm faster, but by how much?  What method might you be leaning towards or are you trying to understand my problem more?  On another note, I haven't considered algorithms that use shift. I can imagine this being very useful though.

Comment: Oh, and 7800basic supports adding in assembly code directly into you 7800basic code. www.randomterrain.com/7800basic.html is the website with its documentation.

Comment: Well, then, have a look at Rodnay Zaks on [Programming the 6502](https://archive.org/stream/Programming_the_6502/Programming_the_6502_djvu.txt) (esp. p. 68). Please put any information refining/clarifying the question in the question itself. Consider using fractions/fixed point numbers in stead of integers.

Comment: I have already considered using fixed point numbers, but they have issues in 7800basic. I'll take a look at this though. Thank you!  And I'll refine my question within the next few days as I have a bunch of other things going on as well.